# How to handle API calls dependent on each other in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

So I have a API call that gather information about an ecommerce `Order`. The JSON response looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 1, 
    "cart": {
        "cartitem_set": [
            {
                "product": 1, 
                "amount": 10, 
                ...
            }
        ], 
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

The `product` is the ID of a product that is put in a shopping cart.

I want to get the product information of that product, such as name, image and so on. So therefor I need to do a second API call to fetch that information.

What is the best way to handle this?

I did the following:

```
.controller('orderSingleCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams){
    // Initiate Controller by setting values
    $scope.order;
    $scope.products = [];

    // Get the order data
    $http.get('/api/orders/'+$routeParams['id']+'?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').then(function(response){
        $scope.order = response.data;

        // Foreach CartItem that is fetched, also get the product details
        angular.forEach($scope.order.cart.cartitem_set, function(value) {
            $http.get('/api/products/'+value.product+'?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').then(function(product_response){
                // When each product data is fetched, push it to scope.
                $scope.products.push(product_response.data);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I'm new to AngularJS so I'm not sure if this is the way you're "suppose" to do it. I don't like the idea of nesting stuff like this.

Any better way of doing things?

Answer (score 0):

you can use promises here:

```
var promise1 = $http.get('url1');
var promise2 = promise1.then(function(data){
   return $http.get('url2', data);
});
var promise3 = promise1.then(function(data2){
   return $http.get('url3', data2);
});
```

Comment: Do you think you can explain a bit more what the exact difference is between this and what I did? What's the benefits of doing it like this? Just cleaner code?

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the serialization server side you could send a part of the whole product instead of just its id. Or do in a new method that has another URL.

Otherwise you could have an url that will fetch products from a list of id, so you do only one request.